# MacOS - "at" command is not working

Tags: macos, command-line, bash, daemon, at

I've started the `atrun` daemon using the following command.

```
$ sudo launchctl load -w /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.atrun.plist
```

Added my username to `/var/at/at.allow` file.

```
$ cat /var/at/at.allow
myusername
```

And created a job using `at` command.

```
$ at now + 1 minute
touch /tmp/x.log
^D
job 1 at Fri Jan  1 09:56:00 2021
```

I can see the job scheduled using `atq` command.

But I can't see the file `/tmp/x.log` created after the scheduled time. Is there anything I'm missing here or is there a way to debug this issue?

Comment: Does [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10467031/at-command-is-not-executed) help?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After checking the logs in `/var/log/system.log` file, I found that `atrun` service was failing with exit code 1.

```
Jan  3 23:29:47 com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.atrun[37853]): Service exited with abnormal code: 1
```

I had to provide full disk access to `/usr/libexec/atrun` daemon as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54539616/4608329), to make the daemon run without errors.